# bubble sort on command line arguments in bash

Tags: bash

I need to create a bubble sort to take in command line arguments in bash (ints) and print out them in ascending order. I believe I implemented the algorithm correctly, but I'm having trouble getting the array of the command like arguments working. My code so far:

```
a =($[@]) 

flag=1
for (( i=0; i<$n-1 && $flag==1; i++ ))
do
    flag=0
    for (( j=0; j<$n-i-1; j++ ))
    do
        if [ ${a[$j]} -gt ${a[$j+1]} ]
        then
            temp=${a[$j]}
            a[$j]=${a[$j+1]}
            a[$j+1]=$temp
            flag=1
        fi
    done
done

for (( l=0; l -lt ${a[@]}; l++))
do
    echo -ne "${a[$l]} "
done
```

This is the error the get when I run the program:

```
bubble-sort.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bubble-sort.sh: line 6: `a =("$@") '
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Use `a=("$@")` with no spaces around the `=` and no `[]`s around the @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is this first assignment of the command-line arguments. The assignments in `bash` shell does not allow spaces. What the below command will mean is that to run command as `a` with argument string as `=($[@])`. You just need to do

```
argArray=( "$@" )
```

Also you have an error in the later part of the script while using the for loop, inside the `((..))` you can use C-style arithmetic operations. Also you need to loop through the array count and *not* the element list. Using `"${#a[@]}"` returns the total count of elements in the list.

You can just do `<=` instead of `-le`

```
for (( l=0; l<="${#a[@]}"; l++ ));
```

Also your variable `n` is uninitialized in the snippet of the script which you have shown. Also instead of `if [ ${a[$j]} -gt ${a[$j+1]}` do just `if (( ${a[$j]} > ${a[$j+1] ))`

A working version of your sorting algorithm would be

```
argArray=( "$@" )
arrayLen="${#argArray[@]}"

flag=1
for (( i=0; i < arrayLen-1 && flag==1 ; i++ ))
do
    flag=0
    for (( j=0; j<arrayLen-i-1; j++ ))
    do
        if (( ${argArray[$j]} > ${argArray[$j+1]} )); then
            temp=${argArray[$j]}
            argArray[$j]=${argArray[$j+1]}
            argArray[$j+1]=$temp
            flag=1
        fi
    done
done

for (( l=0; l<arrayLen; l++))
do
    echo -ne "${argArray[$l]} "
done
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, other than preference why did you suggest the C style conditional over the bash -gt method? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is just to be in _arithmetic_ context mostly! if you are comfortable using `-gt` with proper variable quoting, everything is fine. Since you have tagged it with `bash`, the `((..))` operator can be used for full-fledged arithmetic context evaluation. If you are into portability (`POSIX` compliant) without `bash`-isms, then `-gt` is right to use

Comment: Yep, did just that. Thanks  for your help!

Comment: @AnthonyB Note that in an arithmetic context, you *must* use `<`, `>`, etc and *not* use `-lt`, `-gt`, etc. The `-lt` etc operators are used within `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`, which have very different syntax.